# Cómo redirigir a otra página de mi repo github-pages

Tags: github

Tengo un repositorio en github con un index y ciertas carpetas en las que hago proyectos para la uni, quería ordenar todo en una sola página pero no sé como linkearlas, alguien sabe? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por la poca información que proporcionas, puedo inferir que lo que buscas es algo como los [submódulos](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.